# Having written a library in Scala, can I use it by Java code?

Tags: java, scala

I am quite aware that many threads have been devoted to this subject, but it seemed to me, that mixing Scala and Java isn't that obvious.

So my background and  expectancies first:

I used to code in Groovy and mixing it with Java is as simple, as it gets. Java is valid Groovy code (almost always), and in Groovy you can even implement *pure Java* interfaces, so that these are then used by other *pure Java* code. Simple!

So my questions are:

- Can the same be done in Scala (Java interface, Scala implementation, used by Java) ?
- Will the compiled implementation require Scala library/runtime/jar (it's ca. 7MB...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, they are both interchangable. Look [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/faq/4).
2. Yes, to run Scala code you will need the JAR file. (Check the conclusion of [this](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala).) The size is a known issue among Scala developers. I remember hearing about a stripped down version of the library, but I don't know if that came into existence or not.